# Why are my "y"s being changed for "i"s when using {litsearchr} in R to develop an academic search strategy?

Tags: r, search

I'm planning a systematic review and have been using the `litsearchr` package to help generate good search terms for the scientific databases.

This problem I'm seeing is that when I print my final search string, it has changed what I would expect to be "y" letters for "i" letters at the end of words that end in "y". For example, my review will involve intermittent style sports (e.g. team sports, tennis etc) and thermoregulation, so my search terms include words like “rugby” and “body temperature”, but the output is giving me terms such as “rugbi*” and “bodi* temperatur*”.

Anyone that knows this package or searching scientific/academic databases well, do you think this is expected behaviour?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do `getOption("encoding")` and `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` return?

Comment: Do you have any processing steps which perform stemming?  Replacing word endings in "i" is a common behavior of stemming functions.  (The idea is that it reduces words that could have multiple suffixes to their root, e.g. "body" and "bodies".)

Comment: @jared_mamrot `getOption("encoding")` returns `"native.enc"` and `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` returns `"English_Australia.1252"`.

Comment: @andrew_reece Yes, the function that writes the search string is `litsearchr::write_search()` which includes a `stemming` argument that I current have set as `TRUE`. 

A reddit user has just provided this response to my question: "It's expected. It's applying stemming to words you wouldn't necessarily apply it to, because it's not clever enough to know that rugby differs from (say) 'society' where you might also want to search for 'societies', 'societal', etc."